# Mapserver NODATA affects valid raster data pixels (zero)

Tags: raster, mapserver, display, nodata, mapfile

I have NOAA nightlight rasters cropped to country boundaries that I am trying to display using Mapserver. As such, I am trying to have NODATA pixels i.e. those outside the country boundaries be transparent. The only way I have got this to work is by combining:

`OFFSITE 0 0 0`

with

`PROCESSING "SCALE=AUTO"`.

This works well in that the pixels outside the countries do not appear. However, the raster data pixels now change transparency "randomly" as you zoom in. I am guessing this is the SCALE=AUTO at work - it is possible to have valid zero data values.

I should mention that the NODATA reported by gdal is `-3.4e+38` and Gimp shows the pixels outside the country boundaries have RGB values `-500.0 -500.0 -500.0`.

I have tried setting `OFFSITE -500 -500 -500`. This does not work.

I have no clue how to use -3.4e+38 in the mapfile for NODATA.

Below are a few screenshots as I zoom in showing the shifting "optics".

[image: At default view all seems okay ...]
At default view all seems okay ...

[image: First zoom in shift occurs. Maybe zero pixels in raster?]
First zoom in shift occurs. Maybe zero pixels in raster?

[image: Zoom in again smaller patch]
Zoom in again seems smaller patch

[image: Zoom in again. Different shift]
Zoom in again. Different shift

My mapfile is as below:

```
  MAP
    IMAGETYPE   PNG
    EXTENT          -180 -90 180 90
    SIZE                    800 600
    IMAGECOLOR  "#ffffffff"
    TRANSPARENT ON
    SHAPEPATH     /path/to/nightlights/rasters

    PROJECTION
      "init=epsg:4326"
    END

    OUTPUTFORMAT
      NAME      GEOTIFF
      DRIVER    GDAL/GTiff
      MIMETYPE  image/tiff
      IMAGEMODE PC256
      EXTENSION tif
    END

    WEB
      METADATA
        "wms_title" "Nightlight Rasters"
        "wms_onlineresource" "http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=test.map"
        "wms_description" "nightlights"
        "wms_name" "Nightlights"
        "wms_label" "Nightlights"
        "wms_srs" "EPSG:3857"
        "wms_extent" "-180 -90 180 90"
        "wms_formats" "GEOTIFF"
        "wms_enable_request" "*"
      END
    END

    LAYER
      NAME NL_CTRYCODE_VIIRS.M_NLPERIOD_VCMCFG-MTSALL-MEAN-RGFT_GADM-3.6-SHPZIP
      STATUS ON

      TILEINDEX NL_CTRYCODE_VIIRS.M_NLPERIOD_VCMCFG-MTSALL-MEAN-RGFT_GADM-3.6-SHPZIP_tindex.shp
      TILEITEM  "location"
      OFFSITE 0 0 0

      TYPE RASTER
      PROCESSING "SCALE=AUTO"

      PROJECTION
        "init=epsg:4326"
      END

      METADATA
        "DESCRIPTION" "nightlights"
        "wms_title" "NL_CTRYCODE_VIIRS.M_NLPERIOD_VCMCFG-MTSALL-MEAN-RGFT_GADM-3.6-SHPZIP"
        "wms_timeitem"  "nlPeriod"
        "wms_timeextent"  "201401/201412"
      END

      # CLASSITEM "[pixel]"
      #   CLASS
      #     NAME "NODATA"
      #     EXPRESSION ([pixel] = -339999999999999996123846586046231871488)
      #     #EXPRESSION ([pixel] < 0)
      #     STYLE
      #       OPACITY 0
      #     END
      #   END #END CLASS
      # END #END CLASSITEM

    END #END LAYER

  END #END MAP
```

I have tried using classes but not sure how to do this. Plus it seems pretty expensive in terms of processing. Though I may need to look at this in future to have the bright spots stand out against the dark areas. I can supply a sample raster as well if it will help.

Comment: If GDAL finds nodata from the source image there should be no need to use OFFSITE. Comment it out  and have a try.

Comment: @user30184 When I turn off OFFSITE then I get "square" blocks. The pixels outside the boundaries are black.

Comment: An additional observation: there are negative values in the pixel data all between -1 and 0. Could this  be a problem?